# How to do basic authentication over HTTPs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, https, basic-authentication

After looking a lot, I've found some solutions that seem working, but not for me...

For example, I have this script:

```
require 'net/http'
require "net/https"

@http=Net::HTTP.new('www.xxxxxxx.net', 443)
@http.use_ssl = true
@http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
@http.start() {|http|
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/gb/PastSetupsXLS.asp?SR=31,6')
    req.basic_auth 'my_user', 'my_password'
    response = http.request(req)
    print response.body
}
```

When I run it, it gives me a page that requests for authentication, but if I write the following URL in the browser, I get into the website without problems:

```
https://my_user:my_password@www.xxxxxxx.net/gb/PastSetupsXLS.asp?SR=31,6
```

I have also tried with open-uri:

```
module OpenSSL
    module SSL
        remove_const :VERIFY_PEER
    end
end
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

def download(full_url, to_here)
    writeOut = open(to_here, "wb") 
    writeOut.write(open(full_url, :http_basic_authentication=>["my_user", "my_password"]).read) 
    writeOut.close 
end

download('https://www.xxxxxxx.net/gb/PastSetupsXLS.asp?SR=31,6', "target_file.html")
```

But the result is the same, the site is asking for user authentication.
Any tips of what am I doing wrong?. Must I encode the password in Base 64?

Comment: Have you tried adding the username and password in the URL, in the same way that you would put it into the browser?

Comment: Yes, of course, but that way is not supported for those libraries.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I wrote a piece of code based on examples given in the [Net::HTTP docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) and tested it on my local WAMP server - it works fine. Here's what I have:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

uri = URI('https://localhost/')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https', 
  :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  request.basic_auth 'matt', 'secret'

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object

  puts response
  puts response.body
end
```

And my `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
AuthName "Authorization required"
AuthUserFile c:/wamp/www/ssl/.htpasswd
AuthType basic
Require valid-user
```

My `.htpasswd` is just a one liner generated with `htpasswd -c .htpasswd matt` for password "secret". When I run my code I get "200 OK" and contents of index.html. If I remove the `request.basic_auth` line, I get 401 error.

**UPDATE:**

As indicated by @stereoscott in the comments, the `:verify_mode` value I used in the example (`OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`) is not safe for production.

All available options listed in the [OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLContext.html#verify_mode) docs are: VERIFY_NONE, VERIFY_PEER, VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE, VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, out of which (according to the [OpenSSL docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html#NOTES)) only the first two ones are used in the client mode.

So `VERIFY_PEER` should be used on production, which [is the default](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-start) btw, so you can skip it entirely.

Comment: The require should be 'net/https' instead of 'net/http' (at least thats what I had to change to make it work for me)

Comment: VERIFY_NONE isn't the best in terms of security. Although the data is encrypted over SSL you can't confirm you are talking to the server you think you are.

Comment: @stereoscott True - I didn't a have valid SSL certificate on my local WAMP server, so had to use it, but it's not recommended in production.

Comment: @Matt what should be the value of `verify_mode` then if I have SSL certificate ?

Comment: @Matt If you do have sometime.. also can you add, how to add cert and key with `net/http` ? Or do I need to add them, or it will be added by default by Ruby, when I have those files in a custom path..

Comment: @Arup Rakshit: I'm not exactly sure what you mean - I think you should ask a separate question

Answer (score 8):

The following is what ended up working for me:

```rb
require "uri"
require "net/http"

url = URI("https://localhost/")

https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
request["Authorization"] =  "Basic " + Base64::encode64("my_user:my_password")

response = https.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

I came up with this by building a new HTTP Request in [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), specifying the URL, choosing an Authorization Type of "Basic Auth," and inputting the credentials.

Clicking the Code icon (`</>`) and selecting "Ruby - Net::HTTP" will then generate a code snippet, giving you the output above.

Postman took care of encoding the credentials, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32172779/2566838) helped me to dynamically set these values. You also can likely omit the "cookie" key as part of the request.

Comment: I had to make a slight change in order for it to work. request["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("User:Pass").gsub(/\n/, '')