# Rails Basic Base64 Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I'm trying to replicate this GET curl request:

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic dGVzdEB0YXByZXNlYXJjaC5jb206NGMzMTg2Mjg4YWUyM2ZkOTY2MWNiNWRmY2NlMTkzMGU="
-H "Content-Type: application/json" http://staging.example.com/api/v1/campaigns
```

The auth is generated with an email + an api key this way in Ruby:

```
auth = "Basic" + Base64::encode64("test@example.com:4c3186288ae23fd9661cb5dfcce1930e")
```

What's the best way to replicate this in Ruby/Rails?

Here's what I've been trying:

```
    auth = "Basic" + Base64::encode64("example@example.com@:4c3186288ae23fd9661cb5dfcce1930e")
    uri = URI.parse("https://www.staging.example.com/api/v1/campaigns")

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = auth
    response = http.request(request)

    puts response.body
```

Based off of a few other SO's and blogs I've found, but then I get `undefined method 'env' for #<Net::HTTP::Get GET>` back.

Any ideas how I can set that so the message comes out like this?

```
Authorization: Basic dGVzdEB0YXByZXNlYXJjaC5jb206NGMzMTg2Mjg4YWUyM2ZkOTY2MWNiNWRmY2NlMTkzMGU=
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
request['Authorization'] =  "Basic " + Base64::encode64("example@example.com@:4c3186288ae23fd9661cb5dfcce1930e")
```

Comment: Further question - is there a way I can log the entire request to the log like a `puts request.inspect` type of call? It'd be nice to view the requests when doing the dev

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more straightforward way, using `request.basic_auth` to handle all the messy details:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.basic_auth(username, password)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = http.request(request)
```