# Convert curl request to Rails Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

An API I am using is telling me to make a GET request as follows:

```
curl -s \
     -X GET \ 
     --user "$MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC:$MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE" \
     https://api.mailjet.com/v3/REST/template/$template_ID/detailcontent
```

and I am trying to convert this to Rails' `NET::HTTP`.  I've tried adding a `req.body`, adding `?user=TOKEN` and keep getting a `401 Unauthorized` response.  I've tested it in curl and my credentials are valid.

How do I include the `--user "$MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC:$MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE"` portion in my GET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--user` in curl is used for server authentication. In your case, after `--user` you provide username and password separated with colon. This will be used for the http basic authentication.

Since you know that, you can check how to do the basic authentication with NET::HTTP [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Basic+Authentication) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822555/how-to-do-basic-authentication-over-https-in-ruby).